# line of intersection: error in vector functions

Tags: c++, math, geometry

i want to compute intersection line, given by 2 planes. my main program gives me, plane parameters a,b,-1,d (my equation is ax+by-z+d=0). so, my function for computing equation of intersection line is as;

```
vector<double> LineofIntersection(vector<double> plane1,vector<double> plane2) {
     double a1=plane1.at(0);    double a2=plane2.at(0);
     double b1=plane1.at(1);    double b2=plane2.at(1);
     double d1=plane1.at(2);    double d2=plane2.at(2);
     int c1=-1,c2=-1;
     double cros_x=fabs((b1*c2)-(b2*c1));
     double cros_y=fabs((a2*c1)-(a1*c2));
     double cros_z=fabs((a1*b2)-(a2*b1));
     vector <double> point; vector <double> pointout;

     int maxc;   // max coordinate
     if (cros_x > cros_y){
        if (cros_x > cros_z)
             maxc = 1;
        else maxc = 3;
        }
     else {
        if (cros_y > cros_z)
             maxc = 2;
        else maxc = 3;
        }
     //
     vector <double> point; vector <double> pointout;
     switch (maxc) {  // select max coordinate          
     case 1: // intersect with x=0                   
        point.at(0)=0;
        point.at(1)=(d2-d1)/(b2-b1);
        point.at(2)=(b1*d2-2*b1*d1+d1*b2)/(b2-b1);
        break;
     case 2: // intersect with y=0                   
        point.at(0)=(d2-d1)/(a1-a2);
        point.at(1)=0;
        point.at(2)=(a1*d2-a2*d1)/(a1-a2);
        break;
     case 3: // intersect with z=0                   
        point.at(0)=(b1*d2-b2*d1)/(a1*b2-a2*b1);
        point.at(1)=(a2*d1-a1*d2)/(a1*b2-a2*b1);
        point.at(2)=0;
        break;
     }   
     pointout.push_back(point.at(0));
     pointout.push_back(point.at(1));
     pointout.push_back(point.at(2));
     return pointout;
}
```

in the main program, i call this function as:

```
vector<double> linep=LineofIntersection(plane1,plane2);
cout<<linep.at(1)<<" "<<linep.at(1)<<" "<<linep.at(2);
```

but, i got error message and cannot run the program. any help please.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: @ oli=> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: It looks like you're not initializing plane1 and plane2 correctly - how do you set those up?

Comment: i think, it ok, i have tested whether main program is given two vectors or not. mainprogram properly give the plane parameters. also, i tested without using from int maxc till return and tried to get cros_x,cros_y,cros_z as my output. then, it works. so problem should be within the below part i guess. any help plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundementally, your problem is that you are assigning to locations in the `point` vector without first allocating them. Additionally, `pointout` serves no purpose, and you have a syntax error. Here are my recommendations:

```
 vector <double> point; vector <double> pointout;
```

This line appears twice. Delete the line the first time it appears, and replace the second instance with:

```
vector <double> point(3);
```

Notice the `(3)`. Without it, `point` is an empty vector, i.e. it has no doubles in it at all. With it, it has 3 doubles.

The `pointout` object serves no purpose. Replace these two lines:

```
pointout.push_back(point.at(0));pointout.push_back(point.at(1));pointout.push_back(point.at(2));
return pointout;
```

with this line:

```
return point;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a debugger.  You have some out of bounds access.  For example, you access the point vector while it's empty.

Comment: thanks, but sorry, i couldnt get you. so, how can i follow your solution

Comment: @g_niro: A debugger will tell you exactly where your problems are.  I can tell you that every line in your switch statement will cause a crash.  at(x) will throw an exception because your point vector is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
vector <double> point; vector <double> pointout;
```

to

```
vector <double> point(3); // You need to init the size of this!
vector <double> pointout;
```